# New to Objective-C. Getting a "may not respond to ' new' warning. " Constructor leading to a segfault

Tags: objective-c, gcc, constructor

So I'm new to Objective-C and I'm following [this tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Objective-C_Programming/syntax). I'm running Linux Mint 14. I've installed gobjc by running `sudo apt-get install gobjc` and I have gcc already installed as well. I'm trying out their `Point` example, but I'm running into some weird errors.

Here's my code (pretty much copy and pasted from the website):

```
#import <objc/Object.h>
#import <math.h>
#import <stdio.h>

@interface Point : Object
{
@private
   double x;
   double y;
}

- (id) x: (double) x_value;
- (double) x;
- (id) y: (double) y_value;
- (double) y;
- (double) magnitude;
@end

@implementation Point

- (id) x: (double) x_value
{
   x = x_value;
   return self;
}

- (double) x
{
   return x;
}

- (id) y: (double) y_value
{
   y = y_value;
   return self;
}

- (double) y
{
   return y;
}

- (double) magnitude
{
   return sqrt(x*x+y*y);
}

@end

int main(void)
{
   Point *point = [Point new];
   [point x:10.0];
   [point y:12.0];
   printf("The distance from the point (%g, %g) to the origin is %g.\n",
      [point x], [point y], [point magnitude]);

   return 0;
}
```

And I'm compiling using `gcc Point.m -lobjc -lm`.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Point.m: In function ‘main’:
Point.m:52:4: warning: ‘Point’ may not respond to ‘+new’ [enabled by default]
Point.m:52:4: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature [enabled by default]
Point.m:52:4: warning: will be assumed to return ‘id’ and accept [enabled by default]
Point.m:52:4: warning: ‘...’ as arguments.) [enabled by default]
```

It doesn't seem to be able to find the 'new' method (or maybe alloc/init?).

I've looked up a lot about this problem, but I haven't been able to find much. Everything suggests switching to the newer GNUStep and `NSObject`, but I'm writing a program for one of my CS classes, and I think I have to stick to `objc/Object.h`.

At the beginning of the year, we were given a pre-configured Ubuntu image to use in VirtualBox that we could program on, and this program works fine on that. I'm not sure what is on there that makes it work. Could it be that Linux Mint 14 doesn't support this old of a version of Objective-C?

Any help/feedback is appreciated!

Comment: +1 For learning Objective-C through traditional command-line programs on a non-Apple platform! Good to dust this aspect of Objective-C off.

Comment: Have you tried `[[Point alloc] init]` instead of `[Point new]`? As far as I know, `new` always works in LLVM, but maybe that's not the case for GCC.

Comment: Are you sure it's a segfault you're getting? Not an "unrecognized selector" kind of exception? Also, don't reinvent the wheel, `return sqrt(x*x+y*y);` should be `return hypot(x, y);` instead.

Comment: @bdesham That has nothing to do with the compiler.

Comment: Note that obj-c classes don't have a constructor. They have an initializer. The difference is subtle but very important.

Comment: @H2CO3 It seems to me that in the absence of a formal language spec, Apple drives the development of Objective-C forward by refining its compiler toolchain. "The language" and "the compiler" *should* be two separate things, but in the case of Objective-C the distinction is pretty muddy.

Comment: @bdesham Yes, but here this is not the problem. Here it's the base class library (or what'dyoucallit) is what makes the difference. Foundation vs. libobjc (`Object` is part of libobjc).

Comment: @Sulthan: Objective-C classes do have constructors. In Cocoa, constructors commonly just call an allocator and initializer, but they do certainly exist in Objective-C.

Comment: Right. Even changing `Point *point = [Point new]` to `Point *point = [[Point alloc] init]` gives me this error: `‘Point’ may not respond to ‘+alloc’` and `no ‘-init’ method found`. The problem seems to be coming from not being able to find alloc or init. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you look in objc/Object.h and confirm that it declares `+new`?

Comment: It doesn't explicitly declare it, but it's the same as the file on the Ubuntu image I have, so I don't think that's the problem. =/

Comment: I am not sure what runtime you are using. However you shouldn't rely on Object in anyway. For instance, modern GNUstep runtime doesn't implement any Object +-method. Let alone declaring them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Object` is pretty archaic in Objective-C (goes back to before Next took over the development of the language).

Modern Objective-C is entangled with the Foundation framework (the non-UI part of Cocoa) through compiler support for:

- String and number literals
- Collections (arrays and dictionaries),
- Fast enumeration (for-in loops)
- Memory management (ARC and autorelease pools)

Hence, learning Objective-C without Foundation doesn't make much sense, in my very personal opinion.

You could include Foundation (available somehow on Linux, too) and make Point a subclass of `NSObject`. That should get you going.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've figured out after reading a bunch that Object is old as well. But the problem is for my class I have to use `Object` rather than `NSObject`. And it seems that the `gobjc` package I installed doesn't seem to come wit ha default constructor. I was wondering if I forgot to add something, or didn't install a package of some sort? As stated above, it works just fine on the Ubuntu image I was given, and GNUStep and Foundation aren't installed on it. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Go use NSObject right away and tell whoever they are that your runtime didn't implement +new,+alloc,-init. Don't do a silly thing just because someone told you to do. Just do it right, and tell them why you do it your way. I think that's the point of education.

Comment: @Monolo There are other Foundation-like framework like ObjFW's OFObject. You could say it's some sort of Foundation, well, just fyi.